# Scrape html with request/cheerio into js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

new to Cheerio and js. I am trying to scrape all the pitcher names and their associated stats into a JSON object like this:

```
var pitchers = {
    name: 'Just Verlander',
    era: 6.62
    etc...
    etc...
}
```

Here is the html I am trying to scrape:

```
<tr class="">
<td class="stat-name-width"><img src="../../style/assets/img/mlb/team-logos/tigers.png" height="20"/>  
<span class="pitcher-name">Justin Verlander</span> 
<div class="fantasy-blue inline fantasy-data pitcher-salary-fd">$7,100</div>   
<small class="text-muted pitches">(R)</small> 
<small class="text-muted matchup">(@ BOS)</small></td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width fantasy-blue fantasy-points">
        <td class="stat-stat-width">0-3</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">6.62</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">1.50</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">5.82</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">3.18</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">2.12</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">5.67</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">1.03x</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">0.96x</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">1.09x</td>
        <td class="stat-stat-width">0.90x</td>
</tr>
```

There are roughly 30 pitchers with this same structure on the same page.

here is what I have so far:

test = $('span.pitcher-name').text(); gives me all of the pitcher names, not just one.

Obviously I'm not even close... I can't figure out how to get the children of the pitcher name to associate to a javascript object... Any help is uberly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is the $().each() function.

With this function, you can iterate through each instance of a tag and execute a callback function, like so:

```
var someObjArr = [];

$('span.pitcher-name').each(function(i, element){

    //Get the text from cheerio.
    var text = $(this).text();

    //if undefined, create the object inside of our array.
    if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){

        someObjArr[i] = {};
    };

    //Update the name property of our object with the text value.
    someObjArr[i].name = text;
}); 

$('div.pitcher-salary-fd').each(function(i, element){

    //Get the text from cheerio.
    var text = $(this).text();

    //if undefined, create the object inside of our array.
    if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){

        someObjArr[i] = {};
    };

    //Update the salary property of our object with the text value.
    someObjArr[i].salary = text;
}); 

console.log(someObjArr); //[ { name: 'Justin Verlander', salary: '$7,100' } ]
```

One of the best parts about this function is that it works synchronously, so it's bears resemblance to a for-loop and is easy to understand.

Keep in mind that you can print out the sub-elements of each in the $(this) part of the callback. This is especially useful in cases where you need to figure out the specific thing to need to put as a tag. For Example:

```
$('span.pitcher-name').each(function(i, element){

    //Return the entire element.
    var pitcherNameElement = $(this);

    //Prints all of the element's properties.
    console.log(pitcherNameElement); 

});
```

Now, in order to retrieve more abstract things, like an array of items that are all in the same table row, things get a slightly more complex. In order to do that, we need to use the $().each function on the table row, and then check each child's class for the matching ones. This way, we can keep with the same index.

```
$('tr').each(function(i, element){

    //get all children of a table row
    var children = $(this)['0'].children;

    //this array will hold the matchup data
    var matchupArr = [];

    //class to extract
    var statClass = 'stat-stat-width';

    //for loop-ing the children
    for(var myInt=0; myInt<children.length; myInt++){

        //the next element of this child
        var next = children[myInt].next;

        //sometimes next is undefined
        if(next != undefined){

            //get the html attribs of the next element
            var attribs = next.attribs;

            //sometimes the next element has no attribs
            if(attribs != undefined){

                //class of the next element
                var myClass = attribs.class;

                //if the next element's class if the one we want
                if(myClass == statClass){

                    //push it to our matchup array
                    matchupArr.push(next.children[0].data);
                };
            };
        };
    };

    //if undefined, create the object inside of our array.
    if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){

        someObjArr[i] = {};
    };

    //Update the matchup property of our object with our array.
    if(matchupArr.length >0){
        someObjArr[i].matchups = matchupArr;
    };
});
```

This is a bit of a hack, but it shows the underlying concept. A method that allows you to do a callback on all children C, within parent P, would be a nice addition to the library. But alas, we live in an imperfect world.

Good luck, and happy scraping!

Comment: Wow. Great answer thank you. I've been messing around with this for 20 minutes or so and it does exactly what you said.

Comment: I am trying to extend it a little and I am running into something interesting. When I try to add on the stats for each pitcher like so `        $('td.stat-stat-width').each(function(i, element){
            var text = $(this).text();
            if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){
                someObjArr[i] = {};
            };
            someObjArr[i].record = text;
        });`  It adds one per pitcher even though there is a whole row of stats for one pitcher. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure if you get updates about my edits (kind've new to Stack Overflow), so here is a comment notification just in case. =)

Comment: Thank you Tyler! You're a genius. I learned more in the last 5 minutes from your help than I've learned all week on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [the documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)? If you go down, there is a great number of examples of how to traverse a site's elements.

For example:

`$('#span.pitcher-name').next()
//{['<small class="text-muted pitches">(R)</small>']}`

Comment: Yes i've read the entire readme. My issue is two fold. I cannot find the right mixture of selectors to only return the data I need and two I can't understand how to iterate through just the right elements and populate an object that I can convert to JSON. btw your example returns DOM elements.

Comment: Most of the methods return collections, which you can access like so: `$('selector').children[0]` or $('selector').first(). From there, you can get the contents via `.text()'. All of these are explained in the readme and all the different ways of going up, down, sideways, and reading contents of objects is there!

Comment: Can you show me an example of putting the stats in an key value object?